# CSS multiple layer border?

Tags: css, border

I want to make a div border like this one in this website (the main/big one): http://wiki.travian5.com/tiki-index.php

but all I've got so far is this:

```
#main {
    border: 5px solid #d5d8db;
    outline: #ffffff solid 1px;
}
```

It's almost complete. I just don't know how to make that black line before the border.

Any idea how to solve this problem? I tried researching and couldn't find anything.

Comment: That site is using a `div` with padding inside a `div`. Alternately, you would use a `box-shadow`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is another element nested inside that #main element

for example:

```css
#main {
     border: 5px solid #d5d8db;
     outline: 1px solid #ffffff;
}

#content {
     border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
    <div id="content">
        Hello World!
    </div>
</div>
```

Tip: I recommend using classes instead  (e.g. .main, .content )

Answer (score 0):

Put your current div inside another div, like this:

```
<div><div>"Your stuff here"</div></div>
```

Then just make the outside div a bit bigger than the inside one (or use padding, there are a number of ways to do it actually), and I would use z-index to make sure your outer div is beneath the inside one.  If all you want is a solid color just make your outside div background color black and you're done.